# is there any way in android studio by which I can remove string duplicates from String.xml in android

Tags: android, string, android-studio, duplicates

I have removed string constants from java source and added them into strings.xml file but due to that there are more than 1 string constants have been made for same string **e.g.**

```
<string name="s1">I live in india</string>
<string name="s2">I live in india</string>
```

So please tell me if there is any way in android studio to remove those duplicates.

Comment: why you did that in first place? You should have used same string for both location

Comment: @Vivek: No, OP [shouldn’t have](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/android-strings-xml-things-to-remember-c155025bb8bb#e926).

Comment: @Diti then probably OP should not ask this question also

Comment: No, Just search for it.

Comment: just use `search everywhere` android studio feature (press double shift in android studio) and search `I live in india` phrase in whole of project and find duplicate yourself and simply remove it

Comment: Highlight the string and use Ctrl+F, and it will highlight the occurrences of the string and show how many times it has appeared. That is the only possible way, I think :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to your `strings.xml`, highlight one of the lines, then press <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+R</kbd>.

Leave the `"Replace with:"` box empty, and make sure the `Scope` is *"whole project"*. The first time it asks you to replace a line, skip it. Then go by the next ones one by one and press "Replace" on every line. This will remove all duplicates of the line you have.